# parallelise group_walk operation with multidplyr

Tags: r, tidyverse, multidplyr

Is it possible to parallelise a `dplyr::group_walk` operation on grouped data using `multidplyr`?

In this first attempt at a general question I won't provide a reprex, but if it helps I can.

I have multiple time series for many individuals and I would like to efficiently produce the plots for each variable for each individual.

My code looks something like this:

```r
time_series_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_walk(~plot_function(.x))
```

My `plot_function()` exports a plot per individual. It works fine but it's long and I have to repeat it for multiple measures (heat, humidity, etc). So I was wondering if there was a way to speed the process using `multidplyr` with something that would look like this:

```r
cluster <- new_cluster(6)
time_series_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  partition(cluster) %>%
  group_walk(~plot_function(.x))
```

Is there a way to do something easy like this to speed up my process?

Thanks in advance for any help :)